# Joomla custom fields let a user add their own options

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

Joomla has custom fields, but I want something more.

If I add a field, lets say: colors to a category.

Is it possible somehow that a user can open an article, and add his own options? In this case colors.

So for example: a user opens an article, sees a field named colors and he adds a list himself of available colors, red, green, blue you name it.

Comment: What is the status of this question? Was maleman's answer sufficient to resolve your issue?  If so, please award the answer the green tick to label this question "resolved".  If you still require some support on this issue, please update your question (and notify maleman) regarding what is left to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You may create your own custom fields to use throughout Joomla. Try checking out this documentation first to see if standard Joomla functionality meets your needs. If not, you will have to write your own component/module/plugin or use an extension.
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields